# bitcoin:// URI handling

Tags: browser, bitcoin, rpc

I run `bitcoin-qt` all the time, so I set the browser to handle `bitcoin://` URI with `bitcoin-qt`. Unfortunately that causes a new instance to be started, which fails, because it fails to get a lock on the database.

What's the best way to do this?

I have `server=1` to enable `json-rpc` access to `bitcoin-qt`.

Do I need to set the browser to handle these links with another app (say `bitcoin-cli`) which talks to `bitcoin-qt` via rpc?

Or do I need to reconfigure the whole thing and run `bitcoind` as the server with the running `bitcoin-qt` talking to it via rpc and the browser-started `bitcoin-qt` doing the same?

Perhaps the only answer is to shut `bitcoin-qt` down before clicking the `bitcoin://` link. Seems pretty messy tho.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that when the parameter `%U` is missing from the `Exec` line in a GNOME/Ubuntu desktop file, the OS creates a new instance whenever the application is called (in this case by the browser on clicking a bitcoin: link on a web page). That fails when the application can only have one instance running (`bitcoin-qt` by itself handles the bitcoin database; no other app/instance can be simultaneously doing this).

The "magic" is that when the `%U` parameter is present, the OS sends the request to the running app and, in this case, that appears as a bitcoin transaction in `bitcoin-qt` as expected.

Over the years of playing with `bitcoin.desktop`, I had managed to lose that parameter somehow. Very confusing.